# how to connect to the MySQL database in phonegap?

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, jquery-mobile

**What can give recommendations on how to connect mysql database phonegap in my program, i use phonegap with jquerymobile?**

Answer (score 0):

For Connecting with MySQL Database, you need to create a web service using PHP for JSON-based output.

```
 1. Create MySQL Database
 2. Create JSON Based Web Service using PHP / JSP / ASP whatever.
 3. Use Jquery  POST data from the web service &
    display them on your PhoneGap application
```

Answer (score 0):

You  are not able to connect directly to any remote database from phonegap as it is a client side app(you should not do also, because of security reasons). You need a Web API Server(Java,PHP,C#,Python etc.), which handles incoming requests coming from phonegap, executes them using database then returns formatted data to phonegap app.